# c# how to get selected Item value from ListView controller by single event Handler

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a List view controller with no items loading fro  database. when a item selected I need to get a unique value from it into a single event handler. I populated the listview like follow,

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageList imlist = new ImageList();

            listView1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
            listView1.LargeImageList = imlist;
            imlist.ImageSize = new Size(50,50);

            MydbConnection db = new MydbConnection();
            MySqlConnection con = db.connection();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "select * from categories where online = 1";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dataReader;
            dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int i=0;
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                imlist.Images.Add("", Image.FromFile(@"./categories/" + dataReader.GetString(2)));
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                lvi.ImageIndex = int.Parse(dataReader.GetString(0));
                lvi.Text = dataReader.GetString(1);
                lvi.Tag = dataReader.GetString(0);
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                imlist.ImageSize = new Size(50, 50);

               listView1.ItemActivate += CategoryItemsclick;

                i++;
            }

        }
```

also I created another function to collect each `listView1.item` value.

```
  void CategoryItemsclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem li = sender as ListViewItem;
            MessageBox.Show(li.Text);           

        }
```

I couldnt pass the value through `listView1.ItemActivate += CategoryItemsclick;`  also I couldnt find `listView1.item` `CLICK` event. How can I pass Listview.item value into `CategoryItemsclick()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the listView1.SelectedItems method, and in this case you get the actual Items.